# PHP preg_replace - delete all text except html tags IMG

Tags: php, text, preg-replace, image

```
$var = "text<img src='/img/tag1.gif' alt='' />
text text text text text <i>-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah</i> 
<img src='/img/tag2.gif' alt='' />
<img src='/img/myhome.gif' alt='' />
<b>text</b> text text blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah 
<img src='/img/age.gif' alt='' />";

$var = preg_replace('/(<img(.+?)>)/i', '', $var);

echo $var;
```

How do I in this text replace all text content except IMG tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind removing newlines, you can use this one:

```
<?php
$var = preg_replace('#.*?(<img.+?>).*?#is', '$1', $var);
```

Answer (score 2):

To strip any non-img tags PHPs [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) would easier:

```
$var = strip_tags($var, "<img>");
```

Removing just text is cumbersome, and it's much easier to extract than remove in this case:

```
preg_match_all('#<img\b[^>]*>#', $var, $match);
$var = implode("\n", $match[0]);
```

Comment: I think that he is trying to replace all content except <img> tags. This does the opposite.